# convert csv file to nc(netcdf) file using xarray

Tags: numpy, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I want to convert the CSV file storing date, temperature values, latitude, and longitude information to NetCDF file format having three-dimension.

My dataframe is like:

[image]

When I use this script below it only contains 1 dimension.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import xarray as xr
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    xr = df.to_xarray()
    nc=xr.to_netcdf('my_netcdf.nc')
```

Can you help me with that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set time etc. as indices in pandas first. So modify your code to something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df = df.set_index(["time", "lon", "lat"]
xr = df.to_xarray()
nc=xr.to_netcdf('my_netcdf.nc')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is an issue with the script. My data has different location and information on the same dates. For example, on one line May 1, 2001 data: 15 lat 15, long 25. On the other line May 1, 2001 data: 20 lat: 20 long: 5. This code records the same dates in a different location. I want the dates to be combined.

Comment: There is no issue with the script. You did not state this other issue in the original question. My script solves the problem in your question. If you have another problem, please amend the question